# Facing issue in running echo command for i2c inside docker container

Tags: linux, docker, raspberry-pi, docker-compose, echo

I am facing an issue when running the command `echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device` inside a docker container.

## Configuration =>

I have a raspberry pi 3 b+

Host os is Raspbian.

**Docker version** =>

```
# docker --version
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
```

**Docker compose version** =>

```
# docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896
```

I have a Docker container, for instance, let's name it `Test`.

1. `docker-compose.yml` =>

```
version: '3'
    Test:
    volumes:
      - '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro'
      - '/sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device:/sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device'
      - '/lib/modules:/lib/modules'
      - '/dev:/host/dev'
      - '/proc:/host/proc'
      - '/boot:/host/boot'
      - '/lib/modules:/host/lib/modules'
      - '/usr:/host/usr'
    build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Test/Dockerfile
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    tty: true
    network_mode: host
    cap_add:
     - SYS_RAWIO
    devices:
     - "/dev/i2c-1:/dev/i2c-1"
     - "/dev/mem:/dev/mem"
     - "/dev/ttyACM0:/dev/ttyACM0"
```

2. `Dockerfile` =>

```
FROM balenalib/armv7hf-debian-python:3-stretch

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python-smbus \
    i2c-tools \
    kmod \
    ntpdate

ENV INITSYSTEM=on
ENV DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS unix:path=/host/run/dbus/system_bus_socket

USER root

ENV UDEV=on

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/Test

COPY Test .

# Adding Permission for running script daily
RUN ["chmod","+x","/usr/src/app/Test/Others/TestScript.sh"]

CMD ["/usr/src/app/Test/start.sh"]
```

3. `start.sh` =>

```
sudo modprobe rtc-ds1307
echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
```

I am running the docker container using `docker-compose up -d` command.

## Problem =>

1. When I run my container I get the following error =>

```
# echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

2. I have also tried checking if the cat command works for the above path

```
# cat /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
cat: /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device: Input/output error
```

3. To confirm if the echo was working properly I tried the following command =>

```
# echo 'hello world' > /root/test.txt
# cat /root/test.txt
hello world

--- Another try ---

# echo ds1307 0x68 > /root/test.txt
# cat /root/test.txt
ds1307 0x68
```

#### Note=>

1. I have tried **point 2** and **point 3** from problem section by entering the docker container using the following command =>
   `docker exec -it --privileged --user=root <container_id> /bin/bash`
2. I have verified if the `echo ds1307 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device` is working properly on the Host OS without any issue.

Comment: It seems like it’d be easier (and more successful) to run this command directly on the host.  Docker _by design_ makes it difficult to access host hardware devices and low-level configuration like this, and it seems like you actively don’t want its isolation here.